# Как закрыть вкладку

Tags: c#

У меня стоит FormBorderStyle = None и на кнопка для выхода у меня код Application.Exit(); в приложении у меня есть еще одна кнопка которая открывает новую форму также с FormBorderStyle = None, как мне сделать чтобы закрывалась именно новая вкладка а не всё приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На новой форме используй `this.Close()` вместо `Application.Exit()`